# value map is not a member of Product with java.io.Serializable

Tags: scala

I'm trying to return a list of objects after running the query to get the results from db with a helper function.

```
val clcIdList = getClcIdsList(grades, subjects, organizationId)
      if(clcIdList.size > 0) {
        DB.withConnection { implicit  c =>
          val conceptQuery = SQL(
            """
              select tc.concept_code, concept_name
              from tbl_concepts tc
              inner join tbl_concepts_clc_maps con_clc
                  on con_clc.concept_code = tc.concept_code
              where con_clc.clc_id in ({clc_ids}) and
                  organization_id = {org_id}
              limit {limit} offset {offset}
            """
          ).on("clc_ids" -> clcIdList.toSeq,
            "org_id" -> organizationId,
            "offset" -> skipoffset,
            "limit" -> conceptLimit)
      } 
    }
```

Followed by that I use a map on the result to convert the objects list to a json list and return the response to the client. The below is the segment from the controller

```
val filteredConceptJsonList = filteredConceptsList.map { concept =>
          concept.getJsonForObject();
        }.toList
        Ok(Json.toJson(JsArray(filteredConceptJsonList)))
```

In the helper function I will check for a condition and only if the condition passes I'll run the query and return the object list. In such a case if the condition       `if(clcIdList.size > 0)` fails I return None. But this cause a compile time error.

```
value map is not a member of Product with java.io.Serializable
```

What should I return when the conditions fails and how should I handle it in the controller ?

Comment: Please properly indent/format the code you ask help about.

Comment: You need to share the signature of `getClcIdsList`. If not explicit return type, set it.

Comment: That `if` needs an `else` block to return something if the test fails. Or use `Option.when`